# Can't start activity from fragment in setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to start a new activity from list view items from a fragment. But this isn't working. Here's the code:

```
public class SettingsF extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    String[] menuitems = {"Context Setup", "Set-Up Custom Texts"};
    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listview_settings);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuitems);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1){
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), contactselect.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

Comment: It will goto next activity , if you click on second item( position is 1) of listview only

Comment: what is the use of   if (position == 1) ? it's can't go next activity until found position =1.

Comment: No need to vote down if you know so much. Thanks btw

Comment: And please try searching question before asking a question. You can read here [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) else you will get downvotes :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use event listener on ListView then you can use listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapetView).  This (setOnClickListener) listener can't work on listview.

Listview contain multiple data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to open an activity on item clicked:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                // your code
            }

        });
```